# Angular - Const changed in one component is reflecting in other component

Tags: angular, components, constants

I am using a constant value called `MaxRecordValues` in three components. So I have declared it in a common `constant.ts` file.

```
export const MaxRecordValues = [
  {
    value: 10,
    isChecked: false,
  },
  {
    value: 25,
    isChecked: false,
  },
  {
    value: 50,
    isChecked: true,
  },
  {
    value: 100,
    isChecked: false,
  },
];
```

I have assigned this in each component as `maxRecords = MaxRecordValues;`
This constant is used for displaying a dropdown with radio-button options. `value` denotes the values in the dropdown and `isChecked` is used to show the enabled option by using

```
<input type="checkbox"
       [(ngModel)] = dataItem.isChecked>
```

[Dropdown image reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DIHuN.png)

By default 50 will be selected and if we click any value the particular `isChecked` in maxRecords assigned true and the value will be shown as enabled in the UI. But the problem is, if I change any value in one component using its local variable `maxRecords` then the common const `MaxRecordValues` is also changing, because of this the value selected in the 1st component is also enabled in 2nd and 3rd components. These three components have written in the same folder and have a common parent component. Is it happening because of this child-parent relation or is there any other reason? How can I prevent reflecting the changed value in another component?

Comment: When you do this assignment `maxRecords = MaxRecordValues`, you are actually passing the object reference not the value. When you update the fields of this object and this objects fields are being "observed" from other places, they'll refer to the new value. This is called object mutation. There are several ways to solve this but I'll let you do the googling.

Comment: @eko Thanks for the info. Sure I'll explore more about object mutation and how to prevent that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is pretty simple to prevent this problem. Make a clone of your object in each component where you use it. Just this way:

```
maxRecords = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(MaxRecordValues));
```

This way you create a clone that has its own object reference and is not connected to the similar objects in other components.